# Как настроить проксирование через NGINX?

Tags: nginx, администрирование

Нужна помощь с настройкой NGINX для проксирования запросов с браузера клиента.
Для получения данных с другого сайта нужно использовать кроссдоменные запросы, но API сервиса к которому обращаюсь не отдает нужные заголовки CORS, после поисков в гугле нашел что это можно реализовать используя proxy_pass в NGINX
но примера настройки так и не нашел, может кто подсказать как правильно прописать конфиг в NGINX?
С клиента нужно получить информацию с url:

```
https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=USDTBTC
```

Comment: [Документация](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen ip:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.ssl-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.ssl-error.log;

    ssl_certificate ssl/example.com/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/example.com/server.key;

    include template/ssl_template; #Если нет, то создай

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:локальный порт(например 5000);
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```